# ElasticSearch: Curator concurrent snapshots

Tags: elasticsearch

We're getting this message:

> [2017-08-11T04:00:02,908][WARN ][r.suppressed             ] path: /_snapshot/s3_currently/curator-20170811040002, params: {repository=s3_currently, wait_for_completion=true, snapshot=curator-20170811040002}
>   org.elasticsearch.snapshots.ConcurrentSnapshotExecutionException: [s3_currently:curator-20170811040002]a snapshot is already running

We've configured x-pack curator with two actions:

```
/home/curator/actions/currently.yml
---
actions:
  1:
    action: snapshot
    description: Create snapshot every 30 minutes.
    options:
      repository: s3_currently
      wait_for_completion: true
    filters:
    - filtertype: alias
      aliases: living
  2:
    action: delete_snapshots
    description: Remove recently snapshots
    options:
      repository: s3_currently
      retry_interval: 120
      retry_count: 3
    filters:
    - filtertype: count
      count: 48
```

And `/home/curator/actions/currently-dev.yml`:

```
---
actions:
  1:
    action: snapshot
    description: Create snapshot every hour for development.
    options:
      repository: s3_currently_dev
      wait_for_completion: true
    filters:
    - filtertype: alias
      aliases: living
  2:
    action: delete_snapshots
    description: Remove recently snapshots
    options:
      repository: s3_currently_dev
      retry_interval: 120
      retry_count: 3
    filters:
    - filtertype: count
      count: 24
```

We've added two cron jobs:

```
0 * * * * -> currently_dev
0,30 * * * * -> currently
```

Any ideas? It seems that elasticsearch doesn't allow to execute two concurrent snapshots, does it?

Comment: Is it possible that a snapshot takes more than 30min to run?

Comment: I think not. It is quite impossible.

Comment: maybe you should run `currently_dev` at 15 instead of 0 so you have snapshots running at 0, 15 and 30.

Answer (score 1):

Elasticsearch does not allow for more than one snapshot to run at a time.  The reason for this is that it is compelled to freeze the Lucene segments for the selected indices for the duration of the snapshot.  It would be extremely taxing to the cluster to do this for multiple concurrent snapshots, not in terms of processing, but in terms of how it has to track all segments at all times.  It must allow for new data to be indexed into new segments while others are locked/frozen for snapshotting.  This could create a situation where there are too many open segments, which could deprive one or more nodes of needed memory resources.  As a result, it's safer for Elasticsearch to only permit a single snapshot at a time.